# JQuery: Using accordion panels when visible to toggle another element that's not within the accordion by show and hide

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion with panels in its own div ul li.  There is a second div that's on the page which has a button element.  I need the button to hide whenever any of the accordion panels are visible or open; and whenever the panels are closed, the button gets displayed again.  So far, the accordion works find by hiding the button, but the button will not re-appear after the panels are closed.

I am seeking a little help on this issue since I am not an expert in the JQuery area.  Here is my codes:

```
        ( function($) {

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".accordion").click(function() {
                    // this is the accordion when a panel is open
                    if ($('ul.accordion> li> .content').siblings('div:visible')) {
                        // this is a button outside the accordion on the same page
                        $("#bttnReturn").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("#bttnReturn").show();
                    }
                });
            });

        }) ( jQuery );

Solution:

        ( function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $( ".accordion" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
                    $("#bttnReturn").slideToggle( "fast" );
                });
            });
        }) ( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use the "active" property of accordion.

Here is  a [link to the API.](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

The following code might work:

( function($) {

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".accordion").click(function() {
                if($( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" )) {
                  $("bttnReturn").hide();
                } else {
                  $("bttnReturn").show();
                }
            });
        });

    }) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it did not work. I got an error on the if statement line saying: "Object doesn't support this property or method".  I will just have to do some more research.

Comment: I'm sorry about this. I posted wrong code. Edited the code. Can you give it a try again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I already figured out a solution that was very simple and works well.  I posted it above.

Comment: I gave it a try again and I am still getting the same error.  What version of JQuery and JQueryUI are you using, could that have something to do with the reason why I am getting error?  I am using JQuery ver.1.9.0 and JQueryUI ver. 1.10.3.

Comment: can you post your code in jsbin or jsfiddle? I would be able to take a look and we would be able to decide which version of jquery works.

Comment: Yes! It works great! Thanks a lot for the insight on the size == 0, and your  efforts.

Comment: @CarlBarrett Thanks. If you are satisfied with the answer could you please mark this question as answered. That would help me sort my answer list more accurately.

Comment: I think there is still another problem. If I click on the active area of the accordion, like on the form fields, the button will start to toggle by hiding and showing.  It is doing the same thing as my previous method used.

Comment: I got the exact error. The accordion takes some time to run the code to hide/show div. And the click handler was triggered before this code has completed running, hence the button does not show when its supposed to and works the other way around. Take a look at the latest code.http://jsbin.com/ejecaca/13/edit

Comment: I see the issue as well, it seems like there is no other options for controlling the hiding and showing of the button by clicking the accordion bar or active area without creating another issue.  I may have to redesign this section or use plain old JavaScript.

Comment: The latest code link that I posted solves this issues as well.